# Google Sheets: Issue with Array Formula Not Working for Multiple Criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm facing an issue with my Google Sheets. The formula I've entered only works for a single item and not for multiple criteria.

You can find the link here:  [Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_t9uaHC1gv3Lj-U9FLnd2UDYpRt_kLmxX-zd0w_aRtE/edit?usp=share_link)

Example that works:

=NB.SI.ENS('Réponses au formulaire 1'!C2;"Plutôt FAUX")

OK [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlJOg.png)

Example that doesn't work:

=NB.SI.ENS('Réponses au formulaire 1'!C2;"Plutôt VRAI";'Réponses au formulaire 1'!I2;"Plutôt VRAI")

KO [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfAVI.png)

Where could the issue be originating from? Do you have any leads?

It works with  Multiple Criteria

Comment: Hi, when you're using NB.SI.ENS (COUNTIFS in english version), there is a "AND" between all your different criteria. If one of them is false, the count does not increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your formula if you want the expected output. For example, in Feuille1!B2, you can try :

```
=countif(FLATTEN(
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!C2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!I2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!Q2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!R2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!S2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!AA2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!AB2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!AK2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!AL2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!AM2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!AZ2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!BA2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!BB2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!BI2,
'Réponses au formulaire 1'!BJ2)
,"Plutôt VRAI")
```

Don't forget to change the formula according to the language of your file : `;` instead of all my `,` and `SOMME.SI` instead of `countif`.